Can the pod know its restart count in k8s?
I have a Cronjob. The pods it starts (through the respective job) sometimes fail and thus are restarted.
I want the scripts running in the pod produce extra tracing if the pod restart count greater than 1.
I tried something like this:
containers:
- command:
  - powershell
  - -Command
  - /mnt/scripts/run.ps1 -PodRestartCount $env:POD_RESTART_COUNT
  env:
  - name: POD_RESTART_COUNT
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        apiVersion: v1
        fieldPath: status.containerStatuses[0].restartCount

Unfortunately, trying to save the cron job fails with the following error message:
The CronJob "xyz" is invalid: spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[0].valueFrom.fieldRef.fieldPath: Invalid value: "status.containerStatuses[0].restartCount": error converting fieldPath: field label not supported: status.containerStatuses[0].restartCount

Does not seem I can use status fields like that.
So my question is - how can a pod knows its current restart count?

Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or DevOps. These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.

This is not about configuring the cluster, but about programming a pod.

Have you tried to get the value using initcontianer and volumemounts?

@DharaniDharGolladasari - I am familiar with the technique - have a common emptyDir {} volume mounted both in the initContainer and the main container, let the init container compute something and save as a file in the volume, which can then be read by the main container.
Do you suggest to execute k8s API in the init container and save it as file?

Yes, because as mentioned here so far there is only limited data that we can retrieve through downwardAPI.

I think I get it. I would like to credit you. If you could arrange an answer with some concrete details for the benefit of the others, I will credit it.

By using downwardAPI, we can expose the pod metadata into containers. There are different ways to use downwardAPI such as

as environment variables

as files in a downwardAPI volume


In both methods there are only limited fields available to expose into the container. As mentioned in the above document we cannot expose the restartCount to container variables.
In case if you want the full details of the pod into the container then we can do a workaround by creating a initContainer with a shared volume (emptydir{}) to execute the kubectl command and save the data in the volume so the main container can access the data. Example as shown below
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: rst-pd
spec:
  initContainers:
  - name: init-container
    image: bitnami/kubectl
    env:
     - name: KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST
       valueFrom:
         fieldRef:
          fieldPath: status.hostIP
     - name: KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT
       value: "443"
    command:
    - '/bin/bash'
    - "-c"
    - |
       kubectl get pods -o json > /data/pods.json
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-volume
      mountPath: /data   
  containers:
  - image: nginx                         
    name: nginx-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /data 
      name: shared-volume 
  volumes:
  - name: shared-volume
    emptyDir: {}

In this example modify the image configurations and environment variables according to your requirement.
